# Select the lastest version of rows in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the scenario....

I have a MySQL table (called fixtures) with the following....

[image]

You can see that a fixture for Team A on date 2012-06-01 has been updated and version 4 is the last entry which has a kick off time of 12:00.

I need some SQL to select all the records for the date 2012-06-01 but only the most recent Version, so it should look like....

[image]

Here's what I tried and it looks perfect BUT it returns the wrong ID and times (which is what has changed), see below...

```
 select id, max(version), team, date, time, oppo from fixtures where date = "2012-06-01" group by team
```

[image]

Comment: How about `ORDER BY 'Version' DESC` and you can use `version` instead of `max(version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id,version, team, date, time, oppo 
from fixtures A where id in
(
    select max(id)from fixtures 
    where date = "2012-06-01" 
    group by team
)
```

Assumption: `id` is a primary key

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select f.id, a.version, a.team, f.date, f.time, f.oppo from fixtures f inner join
(select max(version) version, team from fixtures where date = "2012-06-01" group by team) a
 on f.version = a.version and f.team = a.team
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
    ,version
    ,team
    ,DATE
    ,TIME
    ,oppo
FROM fixtures
WHERE DATE = "2012-06-01"
    AND id = (
        SELECT max(f2.id)
        FROM fixtures f2
        WHERE f2.DATE = DATE
            AND f2.team = team
        )
```